# Loop through arrays and subsets in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key

I have the following array:

> Array ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 010 [release] => 006 )
>   [Header] => Array ( [To] => 6891118750001 [From] => 9911557
>   [MessageID] => 306b197fff044421b31c0a2a15e356c1 [RelatesToMessageID]
>   => Resolution [SentTime] => 2014-09-16T12:19:50.8Z [Security] => Array ( [Sender] => Array ( [TertiaryIdentification] => 165 ) [Receiver] =>
>   Array ( [TertiaryIdentification] => 2341 ) ) [RxReferenceNumber] =>
>   RxRef# REFREQ 2.1 [PrescriberOrderNumber] => 13 ) [Body] => Array (
>   [RefillRequest] => Array ( [Pharmacy] => Array ( [Identification] =>
>   Array ( [NCPDPID] => 9911557 [NPI] => 1801849179 ) [StoreName] => CA
>   Pharmacy 10.6MU [Address] => Array ( [AddressLine1] => 65432 Cabernet
>   Turn [City] => Sonoma [State] => CA [ZipCode] => 95476 )
>   [CommunicationNumbers] => Array ( [Communication] => Array ( [Number]
>   => 7075557071 [Qualifier] => TE ) ) ) [Prescriber] => Array ( [Identification] => Array ( [NPI] => 1234567893 ) [Name] => Array (
>   [LastName] => Jefferson ) [Address] => Array ( [AddressLine1] => 5555
>   Labelle Lane [City] => Gaithersburg [State] => MD [ZipCode] => 20877 )
>   [CommunicationNumbers] => Array ( [Communication] => Array ( [0] =>
>   Array ( [Number] => 3105551515 [Qualifier] => TE ) [1] => Array (
>   [Number] => 3015551516 [Qualifier] => FX ) ) ) ) [Patient] => Array (
>   [Name] => Array ( [LastName] => Li [FirstName] => Ci ) [Gender] => U
>   [DateOfBirth] => Array ( [Date] => 1923-10-18 ) )
>   [MedicationPrescribed] => Array ( [DrugDescription] => ZIOPTAN 0.0015%
>   Ophthalmic Solution [DrugCoded] => Array ( [ProductCode] =>
>   00006393130 [ProductCodeQualifier] => ND ) [Quantity] => Array (
>   [Value] => 1 [CodeListQualifier] => 38 [UnitSourceCode] => AC
>   [PotencyUnitCode] => C54702 ) [Directions] => D [Substitutions] => 0
>   [WrittenDate] => Array ( [Date] => 2014-04-01 ) )
>   [MedicationDispensed] => Array ( [DrugDescription] => ZIOPTAN 0.0015%
>   Ophthalmic Solution [DrugCoded] => Array ( [ProductCode] =>
>   00006393130 [ProductCodeQualifier] => ND [DrugDBCode] => 1244616
>   [DrugDBCodeQualifier] => SBD ) [Quantity] => Array ( [Value] => 1
>   [CodeListQualifier] => 38 [UnitSourceCode] => AC [PotencyUnitCode] =>
>   C54702 ) [Directions] => D [Substitutions] => 0 [WrittenDate] => Array
>   ( [Date] => 2014-04-01 ) [LastFillDate] => Array ( [Date] =>
>   2014-04-02 ) ) ) ) ) version = 010

but when I loop through it with this code:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='') {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {

            if (is_array($value)) {

                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent . '');
            } else {
                echo key($arr) . " = $value<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

displayArrayRecursively($arrXml);
```

It prints all the values but not all the correct subset key names are associated.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

NCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `key()` function but access your array key directly with the variable `$key` (or whatever name) of `foreach()`. Also, you weren't even using the variable `$indent`, so I added the piece of code you needed.
This is the function you are looking for:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='')
{
    if ($arr)
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
            if (is_array($value))
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent.'--');
            else
                echo $indent.$key." = $value<br>";
}
```